# Sendp function in Scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using sendp() function in Scapy module to send packet. And it's really works, but I get report:

> Sent 1 packet

How can I hide this report? I don't want, that sendp() write something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the verbosity to 0 before you send the packet:

```py
from scapy.all import conf

conf.verb = 0

# Start sending packets here...
```